# Relation between definitions of a graded vector space and a graded module

Tags: definition, graded-rings, graded-modules, superalgebra

I am new to the world of "grading", and my question is about the definition of the graded vector space.  For definitions of these two, see [graded vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graded_vector_space) and [graded module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graded_ring#Graded_module) (they are basically what I've learned from).

We know that a vector space is a $\mathbb{k}$-module, where $\mathbb{k}$ is a field. So, is a graded $\mathbb{k}$-vector space just the same as a graded $\mathbb{k}$-module? I noticed that in the example of [graded module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graded_ring#Graded_module), it mentioned that a graded vector space is a graded module over a field (with the field having trivial grading). But does the definition always requires us using the trivial grading of $\mathbb{k}$? What if $\mathbb{k}$ has a nontrivial grading, for example, $\mathbb{C}=\mathbb{R}\oplus i\mathbb{R}$? Can we use the nontrivial one (maybe to make it interesting)?

**Further explanation** for my thoughts: As I found that the definition of a graded vector space includes just only the decomposition but almost nothing else, it's a bit weird: what is the meaning of such decomposition if there is no further interaction between the components? For example, the polynomial ring has a natural grading derived from the multiplication of polynomials, so it is a graded ring and interesting. Even the graded module emphisizes the grading structure of the underlying ring. But I cannot see such an "interation" structure in the original definition of graded vector spaces, it somehow seems "trivial" and I feel that there is something I've missed. Does this structure have something further to do with the tensor product or linear transform, something like that to make it not that "trivial"?

Concrete examples are greatly welcome! p.s. I am especially interested in $\mathbb{Z}_2$-graded objects as they come from physics. $\mathbb{Z}_2$-graded rings have a explicit interesting structure while $\mathbb{Z}_2$-graded vector spaces seem not that clear to me at this moment. What is the relation between them? It would be perfect if one could touch upon this specific example. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your grading on C is not a ring grading, as i*i is -1

Comment: Very seldom we find graded fields in practice. For example, any Z-grading over a field is trivial. That's why you do not see graded vector spaces over graded fields mentioned much.

Comment: There is a notion of *graded field* that is useful on topology and elsewhere, which confusingly is not that of fields with a grading — a graded field is, in this sense, a ring whose nonzero homogeneous elements are invertible. Such things appear in other contexts but without a name: for example, the crossed product algebras that people study when working with Brauer groups have that property.

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Álvarez Sorry but I don't see the problem. I mean I view it as a Z_2-graded ring, isn't it? And I got to know the bonus terminology and thanks :) !

Comment: If you talk of a graded ring and not say something then the grading is essentially always taken to be over the integers

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Álvarez okay get it